# How DateTime types should be saved in Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As I understand Firebase doesn't have DateTime data type. So as I think, it is best to use number of seconds since reference date which is double data type.

How can we then find objects that are created on specific date? Is there a way to write a query for it?

I am confused about DateTime type, but didn't find anything helpful in docs.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is less complex than you might think. Just convert your DateTime values to milliseconds-since-epoch. For example, `Tue, 03 Jan 2017 17:35:17 GMT` becomes `1483464918000`. Every major language provides conversations to/from these values and native Date types.

Before you stumble into it, note one more detail: Firebase cannot sort in "descending" order when retrieving data. If you ever need to do this, store your value as a NEGATIVE NUMBER. (Or store a second `myDateDescending: -1 * myDate` value in parallel.) Sorting on this negative-value field will produce a descending sort on that date value.

Comment: n.b. this seems so weird and clumsy but almost all databases do this date -> long int conversion internally anyway, for storage. You're just seeing exposed what is invisible elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but it is still not clear, If I want to get all object that have SomeDate = 03/01/2017 how can I do this (no time part)?

Comment: That is very bad design. I think  they should retrieve the items in order based on what we use to call it. Like LimitToLast or LimitToFirst